# How to greet when having a PhD panel interview?

Tags: phd, etiquette, interview, united-kingdom

What is the most proper greeting for when you enter a panel of faculty members for a PhD Interview, and what for when you leave? I'm in the UK, in case that's relevant.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Academia.SE!  Can you please give some indication of what country you are talking about? Customs may vary greatly.

Comment: "Hello, my name is AgosGag!"

Comment: This seems to be unrelated to Academia, unless the OP presumes we have different greetings in Academic interviews than in any other interviews.

Comment: @J.J: This assumption can actually be somewhat reasonable. In some languages/countries, it is customary to address people with their academic titles. Likewise, academic institutions are among the few organisations that, in many cases, publish complete lists of their employees online (with photos etc.), which is quite unusual in commercial companies. Therefore, there *might* be some particuliarities in academia.

Comment: Pretend that the group of professors on the other side of the table are actually human beings and treat them accordingly.

Comment: @Davidmh, not that it is true, mind you ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're referring to the proper addresses of faculty members at UK institutions, the general form is "Doctor" for faculty members who are Lecturers (known as "assistant professor" in some other countries) or Senior Lecturers (known as "associate professor" in some other countries) and "Professor" for faculty members who are Readers (varies between "associate professor" and "full professor" in other countries) or Professors (known as "Chairs" in some other  countries.  In some UK institutions, the North American standards have been adopted, so it's not completely uniform.

If you're uncertain as to the academic rank of the person, defaulting to "Doctor" will not likely offend.  If someone is introduced as "Professor", then use "Professor" in such cases.

In terms of matters of greeting not related to the proper address of the members, there are no formalities upon entering or leaving that you should be concerned about.  A general "Hello" / "Thank you.  Goodbye" or any variant are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't overdo it. Just greet them in general, not individually. If they are presented personally, say by the chair of the committee, just greet each one in turn courteously, like you would do in any other formal setting.

Comment: What "other formal setting[s]" are you thinking of?